# Electron: Can't hide program icon in BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to hide the program icon on the windowbar of a electron window. I have created the BrowserWindow as follows:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 420, height: 640, resizable: false, backgroundColor: '#fff', icon: null});
```

This however does not hide the icon and still shows the default program icon.
How can I hide the program icon in electron?

Comment: You can try app.dock.hide();

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 420, height: 640, resizable: false, backgroundColor: '#fff', icon: null});
win.setSkipTaskbar(true);
```

API's document goes here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetskiptaskbarskip

Comment: @BoneJones Ok I see, so please try this:
    `const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage;
    let image = nativeImage.createEmpty();
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 420, height: 640, resizable: false, backgroundColor: '#fff', icon: image});`